# I need to show formatted output as it shows in ssh screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, command-line, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Ruby or in Rails:-
I need to show output from below code formated as it shows in command prompt.

`require 'net/ssh'`

`Net::SSH.start( hostname, username, :password => password ) do|ssh|`

`result = ssh.exec!('ls -ltr')`

`puts result`

`end`

Let me know how is it possible?

Command (ls -ltr) is dynamic and
currently output is:

`total 257140 drwxrwxr-x  8 folderabc folderabc      4096 Set  4  2010 sources drwxrwxr-x 13 folderabc folderabc      4096 Set  4  2010 teste -rwxrwxr-x  1 folderabc folderabc        72 Set  7  2010 clean_memory -rw-rw-r--  1 folderabc folderabc 263012352 Mar 17  2011 ngforms_production.sql -rw-rw-r--  1 folderabc folderabc        21 Jun 23  2011 phps.php drwxrwxr-x 15 folderabc folderabc      4096 Jun 30  2011 ngforms -rw-rw-r--  1 folderabc folderabc       751 Jul  1  2011 ngforms_word.sql -rw-rw-r--  1 folderabc folderabc        31 Jul  5  2011 test.php drwxrwxr-x  5 folderabc folderabc      4096 Nov  4 10:52 dump drwxrwxrwx  2 folderabc folderabc      4096 Jan 13 00:00 mysqlbackup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `<pre>` tag. Also make sure that the font you use is one of the monospace fonts like `CourierNew`.

```
<pre><%= result %></pre>
```